# groovy regex for last character with no new line to search for

Tags: regex, groovy

I have some text

```
customer|
name|Acme Tools" ) & 
contact|
    name|John Renfrew" ) & 
    email|john@mail.com" ) & 
    birthDate|GetAsDate( "4/6/1957" ) )
 ) & 
createdAt|Get ( CurrentTimeStamp ) )
)
)
```

and am trying to regex out everything from the last " or just the last )

my expression is

```
"?( +)?\)( +)?(&)?( +)?\n
```

which works fine apart from the very last line which has no newline after it
giving:

```
customer|
name|Acme Tools
contact|
    name|John Renfrew
    email|john@mail.com
    birthDate|GetAsDate( "4/6/1957" )

createdAt|Get ( CurrentTimeStamp )

)
```

Any genius like to offer some guidance and assistance??

Comment: Make newline optional.

Comment: what are you using?  replaceall?

Comment: Yes, using replaceAll..

Comment: Make that clearer. Am trying to regex out all the ends of lines from and including either the last " or the last ) I can get all except the very last character which does not have a \n after it ( clearly can add this first but that seems terribly not Groovy

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the `"` and `&` are optional, along with the surrounding whitespace.  Can we assume the `)` will always be present?  If there's more than one, do we want to match only the last one?  If so, this should do it:

```
String s1 = s0.replaceAll(/(?m)"? *\\) *&? *$/, "");
```